# opening new colorbox from a colorbox and sending data to it

Tags: jquery, jsp, colorbox

I want to open a new page to color box with onclick. but the problem is i am in a colorbox already and i need to send a parameter to the new page. opening the colorbox with normal method is not working. I tried this and it didn't work. what should I do?(I need to send uuid from one page in colorbox to another page also in colorbox)

```
function openAddCarBox(i) {
var uuid = document.getElementsByName('uuid' + i).item(0).value;
$("#colorbox").colorbox({
    iframe : true,
    innerWidth : 500,
    innerHeight : 300
});
$('#colorbox').colorbox({
    href : 'vehicle.jsp?uuid=' + uuid,
    title : '',
    open : true
});
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010413/jquery-colorbox-redirect-forward-inside-existing-colorbox

Answer (score 2):

Try using classes instead of ids with following method.
i.e.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".colorbox", function(){
$.colorbox({
      href: $(this).data('url'),
      iframe : true,
      innerWidth : 500,
      innerHeight : 300
});
})
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-url="Your Link with id" class="colorbox"></a>
```